# How to align the columns of ls command output in Xubuntu 16.04.6?

Tags: ubuntu, bash-scripting, ls, alignment

I have this function in `.bashrc` :

```
{ ls -lhNGhgF --color=always --group-directories-first --time-style="+%d-%b-%Y $newline%H:%M" | awk '
            { 
            $3 ="\033[1;31m"        $3 "\033[0m";
            $4 ="\033[1;48;5;196m"  $4 "\033[0m"; 
            $5 ="\033[1;30m"        $5 "\033[0m"; 
            print; 
            }
      '
}
```

It works but the columns of the output are not aligned. How can I fix that?

Comment: It is the `awk` parameter parsing that is removing the multiple spaces from the `ls` output and losing the column alignment. I don't know how to avoid this in `awk`, but you could achieve what you want with `sed` by inserting the highlighting at the appropriate space-nonspace transitions, though it won't be anything like as straightforward as the`awk` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preamble

This is a case where parsing the output of `ls` is justified. [It's wrong to use `ls` to get data for *programs*](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Here you want to take a human-readable output and make it more readable for *humans*. This is far less critical; if something goes wrong you will probably notice right away.

Implementations of `ls` may generate slightly different output even if they support all the options you need. For this reason any solution to a problem of this kind must be tailored to one's `ls`.

For the record: my testbed is Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

---

#### Code

Use this function:

```
lsi() {

local c3=$'\033[1;31m'
local c4=$'\033[1;48;5;196m'
local c5=$(printf '\033[1;30m')
local c0=$'\033[0m'

command ls -hGgF --color=always --group-directories-first --time-style="+%d-%b-%Y $newline%H:%M" "$@" \
| sed -E "s|([^ ]+ +)([^ ]+ +)([^ ]+ +)([^ ]+)( +[^ ]+ +)|\1\2$c3\3$c0$c4\4$c0$c5\5$c0|"

}
```

---

#### Explanation:

First I store the strings we need as local variables. I'm using `$''` syntax that works in Bash, except for `c5` which is (for educational reasons) retrieved from the output of `printf`. The point is the method with `printf` will work even in `sh`, so if you ever need this function to work in a shell that doesn't understand Bash's `$''`, you will know the way.

Then I'm using `sed` with extended regular expressions to search and replace. Any column but last can be matched by `[^ ]+ +` which means "at least one non-space and at least one space". In the replacement, whatever was matched by the 1st set of parentheses (`(…)`) is referred to as `\1`; by the 2nd set – as `\2`; and so on. This way I can match the first five columns and "replace" them by themselves using `\1\2\3\4\5`. This sole operation is a no-op, until I inject previously stored strings in the right places:

```
 \1\2$c3\3$c0$c4\4$c0$c5\5$c0
     ^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^^^
```

---

#### Notes:

- You may have noticed that columns 4 and 5 are matched by `([^ ]+)( +[^ ]+ +)` rather than by universal `([^ ]+ +)` repeated two times. If it was `([^ ]+ +)([^ ]+ +)` then space characters between these columns would logically belong to the 4th one, therefore they would be printed red because of the background color you chose for the 4th column. Including them in the 5th column solves the problem.
- I inject nothing between the 1st and the 2nd column, so I could match them both with one set of parentheses (i.e. `([^ ]+ +[^ ]+ +)`) and the replacement string would look like this: `\1$c3\2$c0$c4\3$c0$c5\4$c0`. Then `\1` would refer to two columns, `\4` would refer to the 5th one. I decided to avoid confusion and keep these numbers coherent with the natural numbering of columns.
- `command ls` ensures the function doesn't run a function named `ls`, even if there is one defined. This is excessive here, but if you decide to rename `lsi` to `ls` then `command` will help you avoid unwanted infinite recursion.
- I added `"$@"` at the end of my `ls` invocation so I'm able to do `lsi /`, `lsi /dev/sd*` etc. Note this also allows me to specify additional options which may work well (e.g. `lsi -a`) or not so well (they may shift columns without shifting the coloring, e.g. `lsi -i`).
- I compacted options. With `-g` you don't need `-l`; and you had `-h` twice; and I think `-N` is irrelevant when using `ls` in a pipe. Still your `ls` may vary, excessive options only harm elegance. Use whatever works for you.

Comment: Maciorowski THKS!!, that' it ! very well explained and works perfect. I rarely use **sed** command and the syntax for me is a little complicate to understand. I should learn more about **sed**,**awk**  and others useful commands.